# Make custom js file globally accessible in NUXT app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, global

NOTE: I'm stuck using Vue 2 and Nuxt 2.15.8 for the foreseeable future.

I'm not sure what name is given to this type of JS file, I know there is one, but here goes.

Say I have a 'configuration' file called thingMap.js with the following schema;

```
export default {
    THING1: {
        name: "Thing 1",
        key: "thing1",
        icon: "thing1-icon",
        ...
    },
    THING2: {
        name: "Thing 2",
        key: "thing2",
        icon: "thing2-icon",
        ...
    },
    THING3: {
        name: "Thing 3",
        key: "thing3",
        icon: "thing3-icon",
        ...
    }
}
```

and I register this in a component like so;

```
import ThingMap from "~/lib/map/thing-map";
```

and I use it like so;

```
const icon = ThingMap["THING1"].icon;
```

How can I make this accessible throughout my app without having to import it in every component. I've looked though the Nuxt docs etc. but the examples don't seem to line up with my file's code, or they're too contrived for me to work out how I alter them for my use case.

I fully expect the implementation(s) suggested to be a "oohhh like that! that makes so much sense" moment because right now my brains failing me HAHA

Comment: You're using it in some kind of enums apparently. You could put it inside of Vuex and then, you'll get a global access to it. Check the Nuxt documentation + Vuex one for more details.

Comment: Yeah pretty much an Enum. We have simpler versions of this file type that does just that, you're spot on. The only reason I didn't consider VueX was due to the static nature of these files. They're updated rarely so it felt like overkill :P

Comment: Hm, there is a tidy small cost regarding the fact that it will be reactive but not meaningful enough IMO. And it will come with the benefit of being easily debuggable thanks to the Devtools. Not sure if there is a [markRaw](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw) in Vue2 since there are no proxies. But a migration from Nuxt2 towards v3 will be more impactful on a lot of aspects IMO. Also, you could use Pinia if you want a more modern/simpler API. Overall, it's a simple yet conventional way of doing things without too much over-engineering from a performance standing point IMO.

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonable then, thanks :) Unfortunately we're stuck with Vue 2 until the Windows applications that access our web app for their users stop using IE11 (hopefully by mid 2023). Ugh.

Comment: Yeah, it will come in few months or so anyway I think. I have posted my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it in some kind of enums apparently.
You could put it inside of Vuex and then, you'll get a global access to it.

Check the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store) + [Vuex one](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for more details.

[Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html) is also a viable use and works great with Vue2 (hence Nuxt2) well too.